# CSS - Resize 3 images with top-left origin of their container

Tags: html, css

I need to resize 3 images aligned in position absolute. The problem is that when they resize they use their own origin and this causes the images to misalign between one another.
I basically need to resize them all, as if they were linked together, as if they were just one image. 
So I thought they should refer not to their own origin to resize, but to their container origin. But probably it is not possible.

Do you have some ideas?

Comment: Why not give them all a mutual class in the HTML? And then resize this class, which will resize them all the same?

Comment: the problem is that even with a common resize, they don't maintain the the same position while resizing. They get smaller centrally, so they create spacings between one another. Just because it's not 1 image, but they are 3 so they kind of separate from each other

Comment: Can you post a snippet of what is happening and post a detailed and understandable expanation of what you want to happen

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution!

it's possible to resize them through their common container. Just assign to it a font-size with a value in vw. They will resize staying tied to each other.

Of course, the images width must use em